# CSS: dynamic margin on hidden/not hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one element (table1) and below another element (table2) separated by a fixed margin. A button inside of the table open another div (dynamically) between the tables. This div is hidden to startup. I must set dynamically the margin between table2 and this div when is viewed to avoid overlapping. Is it possible?

Comment: If the hidden `div` is always in the HTML, then no worries. Give it the style. When it appears, the margin will set along with it.

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible. The div element is still there, but not displayed. If it is displayed, the second table should adjust itself automatically when everything is styled.

**Edit:** Style everything just like they're all faded in. Then you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use javascript to add/remove a class from the div.

For example:
CSS:

```
.dymanic-margin{
  margin: 10px; //or whatever
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var d = document.getElementById("your_div_id");
//adds class
d.classList.add("dymanic-margin");
// removes class 
d.classList.remove("dymanic-margin");
```